# FOR loop for VLOOKUP returned value in two cell and print third cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Comparing 2 cells value and print in third cell. Both cells value came from a `vlookup` so it has `#N/A` and `#VALUE`, even for those 2 values it should return Not Submitted in third cell

```
For i = 2 To NRScount75
    If Range("O" & i) >= 0 And Range("O" & i) <= 10 Then
        Range("P" & i) = "Within SLA" 'values between 0 to 10
    ElseIf Range("O" & i) >= 11 Then
        Range("P" & i) = "Exceed SLA"  'values greater than 10
    Else      
        Range("P" & i) = "Not submitted"  'for negative values    
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I only see Oi and Pi where is the third cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with IsNumeric before checking numeric values.

```
For i = 2 To NRScount75    
    if isnumeric(Range("O" & i)) then
        If Range("O" & i) >= 0 And Range("O" & i) <= 10 Then
            Range("P" & i) = "Within SLA" 'values between 0 to 10
        ElseIf Range("O" & i) >= 11 Then
            Range("P" & i) = "Exceed SLA"  'values greater than 10
        Else
            Range("P" & i) = "Not submitted"  'for negative values
        End If
    else
        Range("P" & i) = "Not submitted"  'for error or text values
    end if
Next i
```

You have no check for a blank cell which IsNumeric, >=0 and <=10. For that you need to check `Len(Range("O" & i))>0`.

Comment: This works too :D... Boths guys... you were brilliant... Now I have 2 syntax... If Not IsError and If IsNumeric... Oreyyyy thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Test for the error before testing for a value:

```
For i = 2 To NRScount75
    Range("P" & i) = "Not submitted" 'Assign Default Value
    If Not IsError(Range("O" & i)) Then
        If Range("O" & i) >= 0 Then
            If Range("O" & i) <= 10 Then
                Range("P" & i) = "Within SLA" 'values between 0 to 10
            Else
                Range("P" & i) = "Exceed SLA"  'values greater than 10
            End If
        End If
    End If
 Next i
```

Comment: OMG thanks it works really :) you saved me from sinking

Comment: Help me with this issue as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/49476223/9409