# Copy filtered columns using Intersect

Tags: vba, excel

Took below code from Stack Overflow. It was working good but now it shows:

> Run-time Error: "Application defined or object defined error"

I have searched for other code but it at least uses 3 to 4 lines like finding first filtered row, last filtered row, selection and then copying.

Can anyone please let me know what went wrong in the below code

```
Sub Submission_SLA()

WeekS = ">=" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Start Date", Default:=Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy"), Type:=2)
WeekE = "<=" & Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter End Date", Default:=Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy"), Type:=2)
Windows("Overall report.xlsb").Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A:N").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=WeekS, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=WeekE
    Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:I"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("ORCA 7.5").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I guess this code explains my issue more clearly

Comment: `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` part will error if there are no cells currently visible.

Comment: Hi.. It is visible.. checked using f8 step by step

Comment: Where do end up if you tap ctrl+end?

Comment: can you share more so we can have a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: What's wrong with an alternative that `uses 3 to 4 lines` of code?   Also, please include the links where you find code, and possibly a little more of your code and some background.  See "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]".  More good tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I ve edited and added few lines from my macro... Help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep it a one liner:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")) > 1 Then ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:I").Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: Hey thanks it is working good... But can you please explain why intersect didnot work which worked earlier... Also please expalin me the syntax it will he helpful for me to learn more in macro.. such as y used 103, what is subtotal and should i want to use ELSE statement if filter has no value if in case... Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @SahanaG, [read this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939).
Subtotal function # 103 is COUNTA

Comment: @SahanaG, you are welcome. For starter you may consider to mark answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that line would be giving you an error is if **there are less than 2 cells that have values** in columns `A` to `I`.

I can't tell you how to fix it since you provided neither sample data nor explanation of what you're trying to do.

Some advice [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/).

**Also:**

- MSDN : **[Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)**
- MSDN : **[Worksheet.UsedRange Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-usedrange-property-excel)**
- MSDN : **[Application.Intersect Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209961(v=office.12).aspx)**
- MSDN : **[Developer’s Guide to the Excel 2010 Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736(v=office.14).aspx)** (and **[Video](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/videoplayer/embed/cbe2fe92-eea6-4c70-9cf2-d800aaed8941)**)

Comment: Filtered excel has 73 out of 2000 rows still not working

Comment: Can you see data in these 73 cells, visible, in columns `A` to `I`?  If so, could yo post a screen shot and update the code in the question **by copy & pasting from your module**?